# Create database postgresql using JAVA

Tags: java, database, postgresql

I want to create a database PostgreSQL using Java but I got an error message.

Here is my code :

```
try {
                Connection c=null;
                Statement stmt=null;
                Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
                
                c = DriverManager
            .getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/",
            "postgres", "Admin@2014");
                
                c.setAutoCommit(false);
                System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
               
                stmt = c.createStatement();
                
               String sql = "CREATE DATABASE db OWNER postgres TABLESPACE numerique; ";
              
                stmt.executeUpdate(sql);    
                
             stmt.close();
                c.commit();
                c.close();
                
            } catch (Exception ee) {
                    System.err.println( ee.getClass().getName()+": "+ ee.getMessage() );
                    System.exit(0);
            }
```

Here is the error message that I got :

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERREUR: CREATE DATABASE ne peut pas être exécuté dans un bloc de transaction
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What exactly are you trying i.e. the code

Comment: Your question is very badly written and worded. No code examples, no additional information on your setup, the use of "plz"... Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking first and edit your question please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `c.setAutoCommit(false);` and `c.commit();` from your code.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are trying to create the database inside a transaction, and that is not allowed.

> CREATE DATABASE cannot be executed inside a transaction block.

See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createdatabase.html

But some code sample from your side would help :)